# redux-devtools-extension not working in chrome devtools

Tags: redux, google-chrome-devtools, redux-devtools, redux-devtools-extension

I'm using redux-devtools-extension to develop a React Native app:

In the React Native debugger it works and you can see `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__` and `window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__` are defined correctly.

[image]

In the chrome devtools not so.

[image]
[image]

Does anyone know how I can get these to be defined in chrome devtools? I have the redux extension installed in chrome and have tried reinstalling it.

Answer (score 21):

I faced a similar problem, the following worked for me.

Goto extensions settings for redux Devtools in chrome extensions and check Allow Access to file URLs settings.

Extensions > Redux Devtools > Allow Access to file URLs

Comment: Excellent, thank you, man! It really helped thoroughly!

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue where the option REDUX did not appear in the top menu Chrome browser.

1. In "Manage Extensions", I made sure Redux DevTools was active and updated.
2. I reloaded the page.
3. Right click >> Redux DevTools >> Open in a panel(enable in browser settings)
4. Right click >> Inspect

Now, verify "Redux" appears in the top menu next to Elements, Console, ... , Lighthouse, etc.

Redux DevTools extension should be working in chrome-devtools.

Comment: After trying a lot of other things, this is the thing that ultimately ended up working for me. Thanks @Domiserver!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the `COMPOSE__()` in last line, use this way instead of your code:

```
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__()
```

or this way:

```
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

follow this link https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension#installation

Comment: Do you mean call the function? But the function itself is undefined so I can't call it.

Answer (score 0):

As reported here : [Redux TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514758/redux-typeerror-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined) , you`ll get an 'cannot read property apply of undefined' because compose from redux expects all its arguments to be functions.

One answer from that post fixed it for me: passing a function for both truthy and falsy evaluations

> window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**
> ? window.**REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION**()
> : f => f