# Heroku Blank Screen on Deploy: React, and Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I have a Heroku test environment with a Ruby on Rails backend and React front-end. Recently, I pushed out some changes to the test environment and am now getting a blank screen with one of two errors. Either:

```html
<body><noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript><div id="root"></div><script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/main.d825ec61.js"></script></body>
```

or:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
    at redux.js:523:1
    at o (redux.js:87:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (store.js:14:15)
    at t (bootstrap 145a692a3e0162c12867:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.d825ec61.js:30447:65)
    at t (bootstrap 145a692a3e0162c12867:19:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.d825ec61.js:29463:18)
    at t (bootstrap 145a692a3e0162c12867:19:1)
    at bootstrap 145a692a3e0162c12867:62:1
    at bootstrap 145a692a3e0162c12867:62:1
```

depending upon who is trying to open the app.

Here is a link to the test site on Heroku: https://alutiiq-lang-test.herokuapp.com/ Please note that it is a free dyno, so takes a minute to load (if it loads for you!), and here is the repo I am working in https://github.com/migobach/alutiiqLang.

When I do roll back to a previous version, it works fine, but I cannot figure out what the difference is aside from on package that I added: `"react-contenteditable": "^3.3.5"`, which I need for admin privileges.

My Heroku logs have no errors that should prevent rendering, and the build is successful, however, nothing renders.

Comment: Is it possible that my Ruby version is the culprit? The only red flag I see in my Heroku logs is that my version of Ruby has reached end of life and Heroku no longer supports that version. However, when I roll back to a previous version, everything renders and works swimmingly.

Answer (score 0):

The solution ended up being related to Redux. After purging all caches, and testing locally in an incognito window, I was able to see the error in greater detail which helped me ask better questions and lead me to [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53514758/redux-typeerror-cannot-read-property-apply-of-undefined). After commenting out this line from my code:

```js
window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__&& window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
```

I was able run locally with no issue, and then push to Heroku successfully.